# Date ValidationError in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I want to block users whose premium plan has expired after 30 days(though I might change the days later). And redirect them to the payment page. I'm doing this by checking the db if the expiry date has reached so it can block them from viewing exclusive content. I wrote the below codes to carry out the operation but I'm getting this error:

```
ValidationError at /owo/
[u"'expire' value has an invalid date format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD format."]
```

I would also like to know if this approach is the best way to carry out the operation, or I should move the code and place it in middleware.py.

Models

```
class Paid(models.Model):
   user=models.ForeignKey(User)
   pub_date=models.DateTimeField()
   expire = models.DateField(_('expire'), default=None, blank=True, null=True, db_index=True)
   active=models.BooleanField(_('active'), default=False, db_index=False)
   sid=models.CharField(max_length=100,default='1303908')
   mode=models.CharField(max_length=10, default='2CO')
   li_0_type=models.CharField(max_length=100, default='Product')
   li_0_name=models.CharField(max_length=100, default='Monthly Subscription')
   li_0_price=models.CharField(max_length=100, default='500')


   def __unicode__(self):
       return self.user

   def is_active(self):
       return self.active

   def is_expired(self):
       if self.expire is None:
          return False
       else:
          return self.expire < date.today()
```

Views for saving paid users:

```
def two_check(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
      form=PaidForm(request.POST)
      if form.is_valid():
         data=form.cleaned_data
         newtwo=Paid(
            user=request.user,
            pub_date=datetime.datetime.now(),
            expire=datetime.datetime.now()+ datetime.timedelta(days=29),
            active=data['active'],
            sid=data['sid'],
            mode=data['mode'],
            li_0_type=data['li_0_type'],
            li_0_name=data['li_0_name'],
            li_0_price=data['li_0_price'])
         newtwo.save()
         return HttpResponseRedirect('/confirm_two/')
      else:
         return HttpResponse('Oops error')
   else:
     return render_to_response('two.html'{'PaidForm':PaidForm},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

View for checking expired users

```
def check_use(request):
   d=datetime.date.today()
   if request.user.is_authenticated():
       if Paid.objects.get(expire='expire') >= d.strptime("%Y-%m-%d"):
          return HttpResponseRedirect('/pay_plan/')
       else:
          return HttpResponseRedirect('/owo/')
   return render_to_response('eyowo.html',{'Paid':Paid},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Where are you getting the error?

Comment: from the view for checking users.

Comment: this line is problematic: if Paid.objects.get(expire='expire') >= d.strptime("%Y-%m-%d"). you cant pass a string ('expire'), should be a date

Comment: but I don't know the actual date the user plan will expire. That's why I used the field name 'expire'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well on the first instance I can see two problems in your code

1.
I don't understand the meaning of this:

```
Paid.objects.get(expire='expire')
```

You are trying to get the Paid object on the basis of user and find if Paid object is expired hence something like this is more appropriate

```
Paid.objects.get(user=request.user).expire >= d.strptime("%Y-%m-%d"):
```

The other problem is the same as karthikr has mentioned

expire is a datefield not datetime and hence you get a ValidationError the datatype mentioned is a date where data type being sent is datetime

Since the error mentions it expects datetime in 'YYYY-MM-DD'

Try something like this

```
>>> datetime.datetime.now().date() + datetime.timedelta(days=29)
datetime.date(2013, 7, 6)
>>> str(datetime.datetime.now().date() + datetime.timedelta(days=29))
'2013-07-06'
```

Try to send this string in YYYY-MM_DD

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
 expire=datetime.datetime.now()+ datetime.timedelta(days=29)
```

is providing a date and time value, you just want the date - so use [`.date()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.date)

ie;

```
 expire = datetime.datetime.now().date() + datetime.timedelta(days=29)
```

Comment: still the same after changing it.